# How to route an additional action for a namespaced resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my routes.rb I have this to add "settings" as an additional action to insurances:

```
namespace :modules do
    namespace :insurance do
        resources :insurances do
            member do
                get :settings
            end
        end
    end
end
```

According to "rake routes" this gives the following path:

```
settings_modules_insurance_insurance_path
```

But when I visit that path in the browser, it returns the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"settings", :controller=>"modules/insurance/insurances"}
```

This is the full ouput of rake routes:

```
settings_modules_insurance_insurance GET    /modules/insurance/insurances/:id/settings(.:format) {:action=>"settings", :controller=>"modules/insurance/insurances"}
```

What should I do?

Comment: The official rails documentation actually recommends that you don't nest resources any more than one level deep. Your app will be looking for a controller in app/controllers/modules/insurance/insurances_controller.rb

Comment: You're right, this gets too complicated and becomes configuration over convention and that's not what Rails is about. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the new route on member, so you have to pass the id of the insurance:

```
settings_modules_insurance_insurance_path(@insurance)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I'm going back to the drawing board as this gets too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The full name of the controller should be Modules::Insurance::InsurancesController, right?